How to process pure text into a vector array using BridgeTower
guys:
I would like to use the BridgeTower model to process text and images into vectors, store them in the LanceDB vector database, and then retrieve relevant images using text queries. The steps to reproduce the issue are as follows:

First, process the text and image into vector data:

def bt_embedding_from_local_pretrained(prompt, image_path):
    model_name = "D:\\download\\bridgetower-large-itm-mlm-itc"
    processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model = BridgeTowerModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    
    if image_path is not None and image_path != '':
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        inputs = processor(images=image, text=prompt, return_tensors="pt")
    else:
        return
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**inputs)
    embeddings = outputs.pooler_output
    embeddings_list = embeddings.squeeze().tolist()
    
    return embeddings_list

text = "The image features a young boy walking on a playground floor, which is designed to look like a carpet. The boy is wearing a blue shirt and appears to be enjoying his time at the playground. \n\nIn the background, there are two chairs, one located near the left side of the playground and the other closer to the right side. The playground also has a bench situated in the middle of the scene."
image_path = "./frame_0.jpg"
vector = bt_embedding_from_local_pretrained(text, image_path)
print(vector)
print(len(vector))

#output
[-0.4280051290988922, 0.8150287866592407, -0.4738779664039612, -0.8128997683525085, 0.0006316843791864812, 0.4806518256664276, 0.22251057624816895, 0.6701756715774536, ....
2048  #the length of vector

Subsequently, I inserted multiple sets of this type of data into LanceDB, and will now process the text into BridgeTower vector data for retrieval. My current issue is that I cannot process pure text into a vector array of the same length (2048) using BridgeTower, because the following method call requires an image instance. Is there a way to achieve this?
inputs = processor(images=image, text=prompt, return_tensors="pt")

thanks！

consider using a text-only model, such as sentence-transformers or CLIP (which can process text and images independently), to generate text embeddings. You can use these embeddings for text-only queries in LanceDB, while continuing to use BridgeTower for multimodal embeddings.

@FatimaMir
Thank you very much for your advice. I've also tried using the text-only model BertModel, but it generates vectors with a length of 768. This leads to an error during retrieval: "Query vector size 768 does not match index column size 2048." Another concern is that vectors produced by different models may not be compatible for cross-model retrieval, which suggests that my approach might be fundamentally flawed.
